# SwiftUI: Changing default Command Menus on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to change the default commands in a macOS SwiftUI app. I would like to append some custom commands to the 'View' menu, but I can't get it to work.

This is what I tried:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
                .environmentObject(AppModel.shared)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, AppModel.shared.cloudKitCoordinator.coreDataStack.viewContext)
        }
        .commands {
            ViewCommands()
            SidebarCommands()
            ElementCommands()
            NavigationCommands()
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct ViewCommands: Commands {

    var body: some Commands {
        
        CommandMenu("View") {
            Button("Do something View related") {}
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

But instead of appending the command to the 'View' menu, it creates a second menu with the same name:

[image]

Has anyone had luck changing the default command menu's or is this just a part of SwiftUI that's still a little raw?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use CommandGroup, which has init options to append or replace existing menus:

```
.commands {
    CommandGroup(before: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
        Button("before item") {
            print("before item")
        }
    }

    CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.appInfo) {
        Button("Custom app info") {
            // show custom app info
        }
    }

    CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
        Button("after item") {
            print("after item")
        }
    }
}
```

Nice tutorial: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/11/24/commands-in-swiftui/

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is both generally correct in suggesting `CommandGroup` rather than `CommandMenu` and helpful in pointing us to [Swift with Majid](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/11/24/commands-in-swiftui/) (a great site), but infuriatingly doesn't give us the *exact* answer - which `CommandGroupPlacement` for the **View** menu?

To save all others the trial and error it is

```
CommandGroup(before: CommandGroupPlacement.toolbar) {
    Toggle("Show X", isOn: $model.settings.showX)
    Toggle("Show Y", isOn: $model.settings.showY)
    Divider()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func applicationWillUpdate(_ notification: Notification) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let currentMainMenu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu else { return }

            // remove some items that cannot be deleted from SwiftUI
            ["Edit", "File", "Window"].forEach { name in
                currentMainMenu.item(withTitle: name).map { NSApp.mainMenu?.removeItem($0) }
            }
            
            guard let menu = currentMainMenu.item(withTitle: "View")?.submenu else { return }
            // remove sub-items of "View"
            menu.removeAllItems()
            
            //add new items
            menu.addItem(self.recentsPlusFavorites)
            menu.addItem(self.recentsMini)
            menu.addItem(self.recentsLarger)
        }
    }
}
```